# Renaming variable with a suffix within an SPSS Macro

Tags: spss

I use the following code to winsorize variables in my dataset using SPSS. In the line where it says `COMPUTE !var = MAX(MIN(!var, maxval), minval).`, I want it to create a new variable with _w as the suffix. Of course,  `COMPUTE !var_w = MAX(MIN(!var, maxval), minval).` will not work. Any solutions, preferably without using Python? Also, is there a way to loop this so that I can include more than one variable when I execute it? For example, `!winsor vars = roa, leverage, roe lowpc = 1 hipc = 1.`.

```
DEFINE !winsor (var = !TOKENS(1) / lowpc = !TOKENS(1) / hipc = !TOKENS(1))
COMPUTE nobreak=1.
RANK VARIABLES = !var (A) BY nobreak  /PERCENT INTO pc_ /PRINT = YES /TIES = MEAN.
XSAVE OUTFILE = 'data.sav'.

SORT CASES BY pc_ (D).
SELECT IF pc_ <= !lowpc.
N OF CASES 1.
RENAME VARIABLE (!var = minval).
SAVE OUTFILE = 'minval.sav' /KEEP = nobreak minval.

GET FILE='data.sav'.
SELECT IF pc_ >= (!hipc).
SORT CASES BY pc_ (A).
N OF CASES 1.
RENAME VARIABLE (!var = maxval).
SAVE OUTFILE = 'maxval.sav' /KEEP = nobreak maxval.

MATCH FILES FILE = 'data.sav'
        /TABLE = 'minval.sav'
        /TABLE = 'maxval.sav'
        /BY = nobreak
        /DROP = nobreak.
COMPUTE !var_w = MAX(MIN(!var, maxval), minval).
EXECUTE.
DELETE VARIABLES pc_ minval maxval.
DATASET CLOSE DataSet1.
EXECUTE.
!ENDDEFINE.

!winsor var = roa lowpc = 1 hipc = 1.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add a suffix to your new variable name you need to use the spss macro command `!concat` like this:

```
COMPUTE !concat(!var,"_w") = MAX(MIN(!var, maxval), minval).
```

In order to do this for a list of variables you can use a macro loop:

```
define macrowithloop(vrs=!cmdend)
!do !vr !in(!vrs)
    * do stuff.
    COMPUTE !concat(!vr,"_w") = MAX(MIN(!vr, maxval), minval).
    * other stuff.
!doend
!enddefine.

macrowithloop vars=roa leverage roe lowpc .
```